# How can I save the coefficients as well as the standard errors for bootstrap models in R?

Tags: r, simulation, bootstrapping, standard-error

I am having a hard time saving the SE's for each iteration for my bootstrap model. Below is the code I'm using, which utilizes the Boot() function in the car package in R. Can anyone provide guidance on how to save the standard errors?

```
bootstrap_lm <- Boot(lm, f=coef, R=500, method=c("case"))
```

Comment: Please consider adding a sample data set.  You can use dput().  Then someone can work on a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to save `summary(boostrap_lm1)`; it is a `data.frame`. As an example, one of the columns is `bootSE`

```
boot_summary = summary(bootstrap_lm1)
boot_summary$bootSE
```